# (C) Function which impersonates a block of code in main

Tags: c

I'm trying to explain this satisfactorily, but when I call a function I want it to virtually insert itself into the main function's code in the place where I call it, so I can save typing it out multiple times, however it directly affects variables defined in the scope of the main function. What's the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT**: I should probably make it clear I also want it to take a single argument.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: You're probably looking for pointer arguments to function.

Comment: An `inline` function?

Comment: @WeatherVane Variable scope in inline functions is the same as normal functions, they can't access the caller's scope.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps `int x[1]; foo(x);` to affect the variable in `main()`.

Comment: It really sounds like they're wanting to use a C macro. This is what they mean by virtually inserting itself into the main function code, and also by directly affecting the variables defined in the scope of main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a preprocessor macro. These aren't real functions, but blocks of code the the preprocessor replaces before compiling the code. E.g., consider a simple macro to increment a number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INC(x) (x)++

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    INC(a);
    INC(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The text `INC(a)` will be replaced with `a++`, so running this program will print out 3 (1 after two increments).

Comment: I'm not a super competent programmer which might explain why I'm asking this in the first place, I didn't know the #define directive had this utility but now I think about it that makes sense.